# Learning Angular 2 without JavaScript or TypeScript experience?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I was thinking of learning Angular 2, but can you actually learn it without any JavaScript or TypeScript experience ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask). This question calls for opinion, which means it's off-topic. People can reasonably answer "yes," and people can reasonably answer "no." It's just not a fit for SO's format and goal.

Comment: AngularJS is a javascript (or typescript) framework. It would be much harder to understand framework without basic experience with the underlying technology.

Comment: @VladimirM So what would you recommend ? Learning Javascript or Typescript ? If Typescript supports everything that Javascript supports and has additional features, is Typescript the way to go then ?

Comment: You should probably start with javascript, then move on to typescript and only then start with angular.

Comment: @Gigaxel I'd say, you have to learn both. Javascript is the basic knowledge you have to have. And for Aangular2 you have to know Typescript syntax and concepts, cause most of the development on this framework is done in TS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular 2 today works with either Javascript, Typescript or Dart.

It relies heavily on knowledge of one of the languages in order to use it.

You can refer to their [Quickstart tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) as a way to see how an Angular 2 Web App looks like with Javascript or Typescript.

But the bottom line is you will need to have at least basic knowledge of one of the languages to get started with Angular 2

It's also worth noting Typescript is a super-set of Javascript so it supports everything Javascript supports but sometimes the syntax is a bit different and you should approach Typescript after you already have some Javascript knowledge

Comment: So what would you recommend. Learning Javascript or Typescript ? If Typescript supports everything that Javascript supports and has additional features, is Typescript the way to go then ?

Comment: Getting started with Javascript is probably best. If you have knowledge in C# or Java, Typescript won't look so strange to you because it is has similar syntax to those languages.
After you familiarize yourself with Javascript you can probably get started with Angular 2 based on JS. But I'd say it's best to learn a little bit of Typescript and use Angular 2 with Typescript

Comment: Well I am very familiar with C# and I need to learn Angular 2 for my front end of my web app. So would you recommend typescript then ?

Comment: I'd recommend getting started with Javascript for the most basic syntax and form of the language, and then get started with the Tutorials on the Angular 2 website to walk you through the basics of the typescript and the Angular framework

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do that :D

Comment: If this answer helped you please mark it as the answer for future reference